# Entropy of Markov measure using marginal distribution

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, stochastic-processes, entropy

Let $S$ be a finite set and let $\mathcal{X}$ be the set of all bi-infinite sequences over $S$. Let $\eta_1,\eta_2$ be two shift invariant 1-step Markov measures over $\mathcal{X}$. For a finite word $w$ over $S$ we denote by $C_w$ the cylinder set defined by $w$.

Assume that
$$-\sum_{w\in S^2} \eta_1 (C_w)\log \eta_1 (C_w)\geq -\sum_{w\in S^2} \eta_2 (C_w)\log \eta_2 (C_w).$$
Does this imply that $h(\eta_1)\geq h(\eta_2)$ where $h(\cdot)$ is the entropy function?

Is there an example for two different translation-invariant Markov measures with different entropies but with the same distribution of pairs?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by Markov? The probability of putting a symbol at 0 depends only on the symbol at position $-1$? Or could it depend on a finite number of symbols? (In that case there are trivial counterexamples).

Comment: Assuming we’re talking about 1-step Markov, the pair distribution determines the transition probability matrix, so the answer to your second question is no. The answer to your first question also has to be no: take two MCs with the same 2-block entropy. This certainly doesn’t imply that they have equal entropies. Now tweak the MC with higher entropy slightly to slightly reduce its 2-block entropy.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Thank you! 
Of course I meant 1-step Markov chain (corrected in the question). 
Regarding the second comment, this is somewhat confuses me. If the pair distribution determines the transition probability, and the entropy of a Markov chain is a function of that transition probability, doesn't it mean that higher entropy of pairs incurs higher entropy?

Comment: Here's a trivial (degenerate) example. Let $S=\{a,b,c,d,e,0,1\}$. Let $\eta_1$ be the measure on all constant sequences of letters: measure $\frac 15$ on each of $\bar a$, $\bar b$, $\bar c$, $\bar d$, $\bar e$. Let $\eta_2$ be the i.i.d. $\frac 12,\frac 12$ measure on 0's and 1's. Then the two-block entropy of $\eta_1$ is $\log 5$, while that of $\eta_2$ is $\log 4$. But of course $h(\eta_1)=0$ and $h(\eta_2)=\log 2$. You may not like the degenerate example, but the entropy is continuous, so you can make tiny perturbations and preserve the inequalities.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas 
Thats actually a nice example.
Got it, thanks!